# How do I implement geolocation in a meteor schema

Tags: meteor, collections, meteor-autoform

I'm using the newest version of meteor and I've created a schema, and I would like to add a location to the schema. I'm wondering what the best practices are for saving locations to a collection using autoform and ultimately query based on geo-location and proximity.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Meteor comes with Mongo 3.2

[Mongo 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/applications/geospatial-indexes/) uses GeoJSON to let you describe locations using different types of geometry. For example, you can identify a location as a point in space like:

```
{
  location: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
  },
  name: "Morris Park Bake Shop"
}
```

Or a polygon like:

```
{
  geometry: {
    type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [[
       [ -73.99, 40.75 ],
         ...
       [ -73.98, 40.76 ],
       [ -73.99, 40.75 ]
      ]]
  },
  name: "Hell's Kitchen"
}
```

This allows you to make complicated queries like:

```
const neighborhood = Neighborhoods.findOne({geometry: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ]}}}});
const restaurants = Restaurants.find({location:{$geoWithin:{$geometry: neighborhood.geometry}}})
```

(example from this [mongo tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/))

This is mongo's recommended way to save geospatial data with indices and sharding support.

There is an autoform map addon: https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-map/ -- that has GeoJSON support